# How to restrict the number of IDs in the URL to just the one that has been clicked

Tags: html, flask

I'm trying to get the book's id at which its "add comment" has been clicked, but the first problem is when I click "add comment" all the books' IDs appears in the URL how to restrict the number of IDs and just get back one I'd

Here is my html code

```
<form action="/comment" method="get">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row g-3">
        {% for book in books %}
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="{{book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail}}">

               <div  class="card-body">
               <h5 style="color:red" class="card-title">{{book.volumeInfo.title}}</h5>
               <p style="color:blue" class="card-text">{{book.volumeInfo.authors}}</p>

               <input name="book" type ="hidden" class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" name="book_id" value="{{book.id}}" type="text">
               <a href="{{book.volumeInfo.infoLink}}" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
               <button  class="btn btn-primary">add comment</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the url after I click "add comment"

Comment: Make a separate `<form>` for each book, not one form for all. Or use a submit button with a value.

Comment: thanks,Regardless that this made my page looks a bit ugly, but now it's just one id and got another problem in my python code how I suppose to get this id because I got "runtimeError: unsupported value: <function comment at px7fcac40498b> when I use request.form.get or even request.args.get

Comment: ‍♂️ That’s because of something in your Python code.